# maven-assembly-plugin - What does "useProjectArtifact" actually do?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to bring over an old project to maven for simplification of the build and deployment process.

In the project there is one set of java classes that need to be bundled with three different sets of resources into three different .jars.

Trying to follow this: [How to maven release multiple profiles project when redeploys are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041336/how-to-maven-release-multiple-profiles-project-when-redeploys-are-disabled/16041687#16041687) I am trying to use the maven-assembly-plugin using three executions with  in the assembly.xml for the resources.

I would like to not have any dependencies in the resulting jar, only my classes and my resources.
I added

```
   <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

to my assembly.xml thinking that not using any `<includes>` and `<excludes>` this would only add my own classes to the .jar, instead now I have all dependencies in the .jar as well. If I remove this, I don't get any classes at all - not even my own. I would like to have a .jar that only has my own classes but not the dependencies that are in the pom.

I think that I am missunderstanding the purpose of `useProjectArtifact`?

Can I achieve what I want without using  for all the dependencies? Or is the maven-assembly-plugin not the way to go?

Extract of pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>bundle-1</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>                    
                       <descriptor>${project.basedir}/path/to/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
```